# Relationship should be given to Opportunity or Product

Tags: custom-object, relationships

I have created a custom object as CustomlineItem and wanted to give a lookup relation to opportunityline item .So  i should create  the lookup relationship with  opportunity or product ( opportunityline item).Because i could not see the option as OpportunityLineitem .Any help.

Comment: You should rethink why you are using a CustomLineItem and not extending OpportunityLineItem as OLIs give you lots of leverage within the Opportunity.

Comment: @crop1645:In opportunityLineItem we do have a related list displayed as Schedule ,with fields as date ,quantity ,comment etc.we would like to create a visualforcepage and display it as a section or a table  in Schedule by dynamically populating the field as pricing ,quantity etc.

Answer (score 1):

You currently cannot create a lookup to OpportunityLineItem

Your options are currently creating a lookup to Opportunity or Product

Comment: :Thanks for your reply.I do have a doubt is product and opportunity product are same.Opportunity,product,opportunityproduct(opportunitylineitem),Schedule(opportunitylineitemschedule),how these are interlinked to each other

Comment: Nikkey -- a) Product is the SObject `Product2` and represents a SKU (usually); b) Opportunity Product is the user label for SObject `OpportunityLineItem; c) The relationship between an OpportunityLineItem and Product2 is via a `PricebookEntry` object.